# Apache Ant FileSet and Globs syntax to match files ending with ~

Tags: python, ant, pattern-matching

I am using the python module formic,

assuming I have a file called *test1~* in the current folder, how can I fetch it?

e.g. something like

*formic -i '**~'

is not working. However this works:

*find . -name '**~'

Any idea how to match such a pattern using ant syntax? I need to remove all old files ending with '~' from a list of candidates.

Note: it could be that the python package *formic* has an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ant, by default, files with names ending with a `~` are excluded from all directory-based Ant tasks. From the [Ant documentation on Default Excludes](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes):

> If you do not want these default excludes applied, you may disable
>   them with the defaultexcludes="no" attribute.